# isset $_GET the multiple value

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to check whether two GET parameters are set, however my if statement is not checking correctly.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 if(isset($_GET['eventTitle'] && $_GET['eventID'])) {
    $eventT = $_GET["eventTitle"];      
    $eID = $_GET["eventID"]; //get event id     
 }
```

How should I check that multiple $_GET parameters are set?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_GET['eventTitle']) && isset($_GET['eventID'])) {        
    $eventT = $_GET["eventTitle"];       
    $eID    = $_GET["eventID"]; //get event 
}
```

Comment: you beat me :) So I'll remove my answer.

Comment: Shorter to do `isset($_GET['eventTitle'], $_GET['eventID'])`. When [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) accepts multiple parameters, it will evaluate to true only if all of them have been set.

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follow

```
if(isset($_GET['eventTitle']) && isset($_GET['eventID'])){ 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$eventTitle = isset($_GET['eventTitle']) ? $_GET['eventTitle'] : '';
$eventId = isset($_GET['eventId']) ? $_GET['eventId'] : ''; // or : 0 ; better use eventId instead eventID 
//Also better place this top of the block, so you can reuse them without $_GETs



if ($eventTitle && $eventId) {
    // your code here
}
```